# Create new Reminders list with EventKit?

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

My app uses EventKit to read and write new reminders to and from the Reminders app, which works well. However, I've only found a way to write reminders to the default list that the user selects in the Settings app... My question is, does anyone know if there's a way to create a whole new list, rather than use the default list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nope.

Apple doesn't allow apps to write to lists other than the default list - looking through the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingReminders/ReadingAndWritingReminders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH5-SW1) yields no way to do so.

## YES!!!

Looking through some more literature, I found [this!](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders)

It seems that the `EKReminder` objects can be added to *any* list - based on my limited understanding, this should work at least to write to a different list:

```
NSArray *calendars = [_eventStore 
    calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];

for (EKCalendar *calendar in calendars)
{
    NSLog(@"Calendar = %@", calendar.title);
}

EKCalendar *calendar = ... //pick one.

EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:self.eventStore];

reminder.title = @"Go to the store and buy milk";

reminder.calendar = calendar;

NSError *error = nil;

[_eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I found I can create a new instance of EKCalendar and use [_eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:nil]; which lets me make a whole new calendar for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @Undo Hi, Can we create new list name with code in reminder app programmatically?
or Is there any way to update already existing list in reminder app?

I am getting all list from this code: 

       NSArray *calendars = [eventStore                                      calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder];
       for (EKCalendar *calendar in calendars)
       {
           NSLog(@"Calendar = %@", calendar.title);}

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, @Student. I haven't researched it in depth, though. Sounds like a new question to ask here!

Comment: I'm unable to see created reminder in the Calendar App of the iOS Simulator..... Please help